# ¿Cómo unir n cantidad de arrays, con PHP?

Tags: php, array

Me gustaría saber cómo puedo unir n cantidad de arrays.

Ejemplo:

Tengo el siguiente código **EDITADO**: Para utilizar código

```
    $listado = array(   
    array('value1', 'value2', 'value3'),
    array('value4', 'value5', 'value6'),
    array('value7', 'value8', 'value9'),
    );

$regis = [];

        foreach($listado as $sub_arreglo => $value)
            {
                $regis[]=array_merge($regis, $value);
            }
```

En mi variable `$listado` tengo almacenados 3 arrays, pero pueden ser más.

Utilizo un `foreach` para recorrer ese `array`, y con la funcion `array_merge` intento unificarlo, pero al finalizar el `foreach` solo obtengo en mi variable `$regis` lo mismo que en `$listado`.

Quiero lograr lo que está en la imagen:

[image]

¿Qué me está fallando en mi código?

Comment: ¿No basta con esto, dentro del bucle: `$regis[]=$value;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Prácticamente ya lo tienes, solo te sobran los corchetes en la asignación dentro del bucle, ejemplo:

```php
<?php

$lists = [
    ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'],
    ['value4', 'value5', 'value6'],
    ['value7', 'value8', 'value9'],
];

$combinedList = [];

foreach ($lists as $list) {
    $combinedList = array_merge($combinedList, $list);
}

print_r($combinedList);
```

Resultado:

```
Array
(
    [0] => value1
    [1] => value2
    [2] => value3
    [3] => value4
    [4] => value5
    [5] => value6
    [6] => value7
    [7] => value8
    [8] => value9
)
```

Como nota:

Ya que array merge acepta una lista de argumentos variables y nuestra lista no tiene string como keys podemos utilizar el token `...` ([info](https://www.php.net/manual/es/functions.arguments.php#functions.variable-arg-list)) para simplificar el código y eliminar el bucle. Ejemplo:

```php
<?php

$lists = [
    ['value1', 'value2', 'value3'],
    ['value4', 'value5', 'value6'],
    ['value7', 'value8', 'value9'],
];

$combinedList = array_merge(...$lists);

print_r($combinedList);
```

y obtendremos el mismo resultado

```
Array
(
    [0] => value1
    [1] => value2
    [2] => value3
    [3] => value4
    [4] => value5
    [5] => value6
    [6] => value7
    [7] => value8
    [8] => value9
)
```

Comment: Listo, si Funciono

Comment: @TheRiddler te añadi una mejora por si la quieres tener en cuenta

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que debes modificar el código de esta forma:

```
public function collection()
{
    $STEST = Session::get("STEST ");
    $regis = [];

        foreach($STEST as $sub_arreglo => $value)
            {
                $regis[]=array_merge($regis, $value);
                
            }  
            return collect($regis);
}
```

Buena suerte!

Comment: No será `return collect($regis);`? No veo ese $x por ningún otro lado...

Comment: Gracias, no lo visualicé... corregido.

Comment: @AmilcarAngeles, intente pero no logro conseguir lo que quiero, basicament lo que tengo en mi varibale $regis es lo mismo que $Test

Comment: @AmilcarAngeles edite la pregunta para que se entienda un poco mejor

Comment: Las funciones `collect` y `Session::get` no forman parte de PHP si no me equivoco son del del FW Laravel, por lo que si el OP (como parece) no utiliza Laravel no le funcinaran.